# Informatica Developer Launching issue

Tags: informatica

java.io.IOException: The URL "bundleentry://2756.fwk879095289/icons/full/etool16/restore_welcome.gif" could not be extracted probably due to insufficient permissions or insufficient disk space.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.url.BundleURLConverter.toFileURL(BundleURLConverter.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getFilePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.access$1(URLImageDescriptor.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor$URLImageFileNameProvider.getImagePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.DPIUtil.validateAndGetImagePathAtZoom(DPIUtil.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.(Image.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createResource(ImageDescriptor.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.DeviceResourceManager.allocate(DeviceResourceManager.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.AbstractResourceManager.create(AbstractResourceManager.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.LocalResourceManager.allocate(LocalResourceManager.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.AbstractResourceManager.create(AbstractResourceManager.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ResourceManager.createImageWithDefault(ResourceManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.updateImages(ActionContributionItem.java:1027)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.update(ActionContributionItem.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.fill(ActionContributionItem.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.createControl(ToolBarManager.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.presentations.IntroLaunchBar.createControl(IntroLaunchBar.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.impl.presentations.IntroLaunchBar.init(IntroLaunchBar.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolControlRenderer.createWidget(ToolControlRenderer.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:975)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarRenderer.processContents(TrimBarRenderer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at com.informatica.tools.dataservices.application.DataServiceApplication.startImpl(DataServiceApplication.java:15)
    at com.informatica.tools.startup.app.AbstractINFAApplication.start(AbstractINFAApplication.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)

Comment: There is not much information on OS, where are you getting this error client/server, Informatica dev version etc. so, based on the error log, it seems like access/space issue. So, two cases i can think of - 1.  if this is a  derver side issue, please ensure the user installed the tool provide proper access to the files to the service account thats running the tool. 2. if this is a client launch issue, please check java home setup, access, java version etc.

Comment: Please, be more specific and provide information about what you are trying to solve.